# Duvida Passando Array Laravel Routes

Tags: php, html, laravel

A duvida é o seguinte, no meu gerador de PDF, quando clico em gerar, ele gera um pdf com todas as informações que estão contidaa nas tabelas do banco de dados, então estou na dúvida dom como passar apenas o array, que é achado quando é feito uma pesquisa.

Exemplo:

[image]

Esta é minha tela com todas as informações, se eu clicar em *Download pdf*, o pdf gerado terá todas essas informações.

Abaixo é a tela de pesquisa onde me veio apenas uma informação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora se eu clicar no *Download PDF*, ele irá gerar um pdf com todas as informações e não apenas com o que foi buscado.

Uma modificação que pensei para ele gerar o pdf apenas com as informações pesquisadas, é passar o array que contém as informações das tabelas como parâmetro para a geração do URL:

HTML, botão que gera o pdf:

```
<p>
<a href="{{ action('CatracaControler@metodopdf', $catraca) }}">Download em PDF</a>
</p>
```

Minha Rota:

```
Route::any('/listar/pdf/{$catraca}', 'CatracaControler@metodopdf')->name('Relatorio');
```

A função da Requisição da Pesquisa, é a que me retorna o array de pesquisa:

```
public function lista(Request $request){

    $aux = $request->texto;

    $catraca = Catraca::where('MATRICULA', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('NOME', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('NUM_CARTAO', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('MATRICULA', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->get();

    return view('catraca.listagem')->with('catraca', $catraca);
}
```

E a função de gerar o pdf que recebe como parâmetro o array que foi gerado na função acima.

```
public function metodopdf($catraca){

    return \PDF::loadView('catraca.layoutpdf', compact('catraca'))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->stream('relatorio.pdf');
}
```

Mas isso me gera o seguinte erro na rota:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A mensagem de erro diz que a rota está errada pela falta de parâmetros.

Minha dúvida é: É possível passar um array como parâmetro para rotas? Para ser capturado pela função *Gerar pdf*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função (*helper*) permite que passe um array como segundo parâmetro tal e qual como nos parâmetros das rotas, veja o *helper route* veja: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-route

No seu está a passar uma collection resultante da seguinte linha de código

```
 $catraca = Catraca::where('MATRICULA', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('NOME', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('NUM_CARTAO', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('MATRICULA', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->get();
```

**Possível solução**

No action passa a chave de pesquisa que usou para listar

```
<p>
<a href="{{ action('CatracaControler@metodopdf', [$chavepesquisa]) }}">Download em PDF</a>
</p>
```

Ao gerar a listagem também passa para a view a chave de pesquisa usada para listagem (em alternativa pode criar uma método private para devolver o query para os dois métodos)

```
public function lista(Request $request){

    $aux = $request->texto;

    $catraca = Catraca::where('MATRICULA', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('NOME', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('NUM_CARTAO', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('MATRICULA', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->get();

    return view('catraca.listagem')->with(['catraca'=> $catraca, 'chavepesquisa'=> $aux]);
}
```

Para gerar o pdf recebe a chave de listagem e repete o query

```
public function metodopdf($chavedepesquisa){

//repete a consulta à base de dados
$catraca = Catraca::where('MATRICULA', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('NOME', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('NUM_CARTAO', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('MATRICULA', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->get();


return \PDF::loadView('catraca.layoutpdf', compact('catraca'))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->stream('relatorio.pdf');
```

}

Comment: apareceu isso aqui: 

"Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CatracaControler::metodopdf(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

Comment: O action espera um array action('CatracaControler@metodopdf', [$chavepesquisa]), já corrigi no exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro a você, ao invés de passar um array com os valores, passar novamente a variável usada na pesquisa, e refazer essa pesquisa antes de gerar o pdf. Assim não precisa fazer a mesma coisa de duas maneiras diferentes!

Crie uma função na sua model Catraca:

```
function pesquisa($aux){
    return Catraca::where('MATRICULA', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('NOME', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('NUM_CARTAO', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->orWhere('MATRICULA', 'like', '%'.$aux.'%')->get();
}
```

Isso feito, você chama o método `Catraca::pesquisa($aux)` onde quiser, inclusive nas funções de geração de pdf, e na pesquisa em si, e pode continuar usando apenas um parâmetro. Fica mais limpo e fácil de entender para outros.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Não entendi muito bem como vc quis fazer :x

Comment: O que você não entendeu exatamente? Mas, o fato é que você quer passar um array de resultados da sua pesquisa, certo? Então que tal, ao invés de passar o array do resultado da pesquisa, fazer a pesquisa novamente? Mais prático pois, veja bem: Você enviou o termo de pesquisa ao servidor, recebeu o resultado, e agora quer enviar o resultado de volta pro próprio servidor! O que eu disse foi basicamente, fazer a pesquisa de novo!

Answer (score 0):

Cara, você pode passar um Json na sua rota, utilize as funções [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) e [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) e boa sorte!